# Anything like `must_not_use` attribute in Rust?

Tags: rust

In some condition, I want my struct only be forgot by `std::mem::forget`, but not be dropped. If the drop code is generated by compiler in accident, I hope to get a compiler error. So there may be something like

```rust
impl Drop for MyStruct {
    #[must_not_use]
    fn drop(&mut self) {
    }
}
```

It is like [Deprecated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#the-deprecated-attribute) , but more strictly, yield a error but not a warning.

Comment: Do you instead want an instance that leaves forever, which would use `Box::leak`?

Comment: I don't want to call a destructor, but the compiler may generate a call to destructor for me,if such thing happens,I want get noticed by compiler

Comment: OK, and why can't you run the destructor? And how are you going to use an instance of that type, unless if you [leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) it?

Comment: @mcarton Yes I will leak it,do something in the dark side of rust.

Answer (score 1):

There is no compile-time solution for this. The usual method for this is to `panic!()` in `drop`.